# Why do we use the t test statistic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, standard-error

I am trying to understand the rationale behind the t-test. To explain my question(s), let's assume a simple scenario in which we want to do a one-sided test whether the mean of a sampled random variable $X$ is greater than zero.

Due to the central limit theorem, we know that the sampling distribution of our sample mean approaches the normal distribution (for increasing $N$) and has standard deviation $SE_X$. My question is: why don't we use the sample distribution itself to do our statistical test? We make our sampling distribution a null distribution by centering it at 0 and compute the area to the right of $\bar{X}$. Shouldn't this give us the p-value? Why the detour with computing a t test statistic?

[**Edit:** based on the comments I see the point about the uncertainty about the standard deviation of the sampling distribution. But even so, would it not be possible to marginalize over the uncertainty of this standard deviation when computing the corresponding area under the sampling distribution?]

I know that the way the t-test is typically introduced is by first looking at the z-test and then discussing the case that the population variance is unknown. But I don't really see how that answers the question why to use a test statistic in first place?

So to summarize my questions:

1. Why is the p-value not computed directly based on the sampling distribution? What is the rationale of using a test statistic in general?
2. Would the approach based on the sampling distribution yield the same p-value as a t-test?  (I think it would for a z-test, but I would assume not in case of a t-test)

[**Edit:** removed question 3) to make the overall post less complex]

Thankful for any hints :-)

Comment: Your sample has a single sample mean. How to know the distribution of it under the null hypothesis?

Comment: That is a good pointer, thanks. I would assume a normal distribution with the same argument as for the sampling distribution itself, mean 0, but indeed the question is: can I assume that the sampling distribution *under the null* has the same variance as my actual sampling distribution (for which my variance estimate is $SE_X^2$)?

Comment: My question then would be: if I don't know the distribution of the *mean* under the null, what's the intuition then that I do know the distribution of *mean/SE* under the null, as posed by the t-test?

Comment: You know the *mean* because you have set it in specifying the hypothesis. You don't need to know anything about the population variance (except that it is the same for all observations). This is quite beautiful, in my view.

Comment: By "you don't need to know anything about the population variance" you refer to the fact that the t-distribution is only dependent on $N$?
To consolidate this with your first point, is it correct to say that for the unstandardized mean, I don't know the exact sampling distribution under the null, because I don't know its exact variance (only an estimate $SE_X$ with uncertainty), whereas for the standardized mean (t-value) I know the exact null hypothesis distribution, because the t-distribution depends only on $N$ (which I know exactly)?

Comment: Yes, quite like this!

Comment: Thanks! This addresses part of my question. Though I still wonder whether one could not directly use the sampling distribution as a null (i.e. by setting its mean to 0) and then marginalize over the possible values of its uncertain standard deviation $SE_x$ (assuming the sampling distribution of the standard error is known).

Comment: You don't know the sampling distribution because you have only one sample.

Comment: Well, I know the theoretical sampling distribution (not my term, but that's how text books refer to it). It's a normal distribution with mean $\bar{X}$ and standard deviation $SE_X$. So I know the sampling distribution in much the same way as I know the null distribution in a z- or t-test -- I make an educated assumption based on the central limit theorem. Also these null distributions are"theoretical" and not empirical, right?

Comment: Marginalizing over $s_X$ is exactly how the t-distribution arises. It gives a location-scale t-distribution for $\bar{X}$ though, which is then standardized using the test statistic just for ease of interpretation, similar to how we standardize the normal. One issue with just using the raw location-scale t is that asymptotically it converges to a point mass because $SE_X$ goes to $0$, hence making asymptotic arguments around the t-test mathematically rigorous requires standardization to fix the standard error in place.

Comment: These kinds of discussions remind us of the non-intuitiveness of assuming what you're trying to discover and envisioning a stream of new samples, as opposed to a [Bayesian t-test](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/htest#bayesian-methods) that provides the probability that the true unknown mean is positive given **this** dataset which may be unrepeatable.  All while not assuming normality.  And please don't bring the CLT into a discussion that is about finite $N$.

Comment: Awesome @Matenmakkers, this not only explains the link between the sampling distribution and the (non-standardized) t-distribution, but also why it makes sense to use a standardized test statistic. In nearly all explanations of the t-test, the definition of the t-value just "falls from the sky" without explanation.

Comment: @Matenmakkers, just to follow up on the reason for the standardization: what exactly is becoming more easy to interprete? Do you mean the t-value itself as a quantity that can be compared between studies? Or is there something else that becomes easier to interprete? I'm asking because I wonder whether we mainly use t for historic reasons (t-tables). I'm not sure I fully understand your point about the asymptotic case of $SE_X$ going to zero, since it feels (from a quite naive perspective) we just 'outsource' this problem to the computation of the t-value which is undefined when $SE_X=0$.

Comment: Yes if you just use the raw $\bar{X}$ we got from the null distribution, we need more information like the mean and variance of the null distribution to be able to interpret that result. T and Z are what's called pivotal quantities, they don't depend on other parameters anymore and as such contain all information on the result of the inferential test. On the asymptotics, if SE goes to 0 we can't talk about convergence in distribution. Then we can't make the usual argument that the t-test is robust to non-normality because the quantity converges in distribution to a T under mild conditions.

Comment: Thanks! I sort of understand (missing some mathematical background here and there). Would you agree though that practically we would get the same p-value whether we use $t$ in combination with the standardized t-distribution or whether we use $\bar{X}$ with the non-standardized t-distribution (perhaps with the exception of some extreme cases)? I.e. the asymptotic argument is largely a theoretical one?

Comment: You would get the same p-value in these cases without standardizing yes. With other kinds of tests statistics though, like chi square tests or F-tests or many other test statistics, there might not really be an unstandardized form. When calculating F as a ratio of variances for example, one directly gets a pivotal quantity. I think it's just to keep everything consistent that in every case we reduce the problem to a test statistic that contains all information. It makes every test mathematically the same procedure, which is very handy for theory, and makes things less confusing in practice.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks a lot, this has been very helpful!